# Mysql, stored procedure for full text search producing partially correct results

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, full-text-search

I created the following tables and stored procedure in mysql with loop. It seems to partially work.

```
DROP table if EXISTS x; 
DROP table if exists y; 
DROP TABLE if EXISTS z; 

CREATE TABLE x (`code` VARCHAR(10) not null primary key, 
description text, fulltext key(description));

INSERT INTO x
VALUES(2111,'rice, husked'),
('0113','rice, paddy'),
('0124','fish, fresh'),
(2225,'beef meat'),
('0114','bananas'),
('0115','mango');

CREATE TABLE y (section text not null, `code` text);

INSERT INTO y
values('food', 'rice local'),
('food', 'rice imported'),
('food', 'beer'),
('food', 'banana');

create table z (section text not null, `code` text, cpc VARCHAR(10)   
NULL);

drop procedure if exists fmatch;
delimiter //
create procedure fmatch()
language sql
deterministic
sql security definer
begin

declare v_code VARCHAR(10);
declare v_description text;
declare v_finished int;
    declare c cursor for select * from x ;
declare continue handler for not found set v_finished=1;

delete from z;

open c;
 c_loop: loop
   fetch c into v_code,v_description;
  if v_finished then
    leave c_loop;
  end if;

insert into z 
        select y.section, y.`code`, v_code
 from y where match (y.`code`) against (v_description in boolean mode);
end loop c_loop;
close c;

select * from z;
end//
delimiter ;

call fmatch();
```

The result produced here as:

```
section   code             cpc

food      rice local       2111
food      rice imported    2111
food      rice local       0113
food      rice imported    0113
```

Instead, I want the resulting table as:

```
section   code             cpc

food      banana           0114
food      beer             null
food      rice local       0113
food      rice imported    0113
```

I am seeking your advice where I am wrong.

Comment: and why is it that you think that should be the output? You need to throw a  lot of data at FTS to make it work. You train it. Think thousands of rows with stopwords.

Comment: @Drew, even if for small set of data it should give correct mapping. Note this is a test case only that I am trying. is the wrong in looping structure?

Comment: FTS is not Abdullah in charge, like non-FTS. It is handing it over to a fuzzy engine to make the best choice. and that comes with volume which is clearly stated  in the manual. So don't confused FTS with non-FTS

Answer (score 0):

I did the above mapping exercise with a different database that I have. Below are the two databases - one came from survey data and other from UN classification system. I tried to match survey data (on various expenditure items) with that in UN classification system.

However, as the raw data is raw meaning having different nomenclature, the results(matching) are not that great. Even the procedure below doesn't produce partial words matching, e.g. mango (from raw data) was not mapped to mangoes.

In the boolean mode you can include match(column1, column2..) against('mango*' in boolean mode) and it will produce partial word matching. In the similarly fashion I thought of putting asterisk on the column v_code in the below code but that would not work. If anyone has other idea, most welcome.

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo_CPC
 ADD FULLTEXT(`CODE`, description); 

 ALTER TABLE SLE11_MCPC
 ADD FULLTEXT(`CODE`, Section, MCPC); 

 drop procedure if exists SLE11_CPC_Mapping;
 delimiter //
 create procedure SLE11_CPC_Mapping()
 language sql
 DETERMINISTIC
 sql security definer
  begin
  declare v_section VARCHAR(10);
  declare v_code text;
  declare v_mcpc VARCHAR(10); 
  declare v_finished int;
   declare c cursor for select * from SLE11_MCPC;
   declare continue handler for not found set v_finished=1;

  DELETE from SLE11_MCPC; 

    open c;
  c_loop: loop
   fetch c into v_section, v_code, v_mcpc; 
   if v_finished then
    leave c_loop;
end if;

  insert into SLE11_MCPC 
        select v_section, v_code, left(dbo_CPC.`code`,4)
 from dbo_CPC where match (dbo_CPC.Description) against (v_code in 
    boolean MODE)
     LIMIT 1;
end loop c_loop;
close c;

 end//
delimiter ;
```